# Https Connector of Jetty 9 embedded not created

Tags: ssl, jetty, osgi, embedded-jetty

I am using Jetty 9.2.7.v20150116 within OSGi and I must create a Https Connector, but it is not working. I have created a fragment bundle that contains the jetty.xml with the following content:

```
<New id="httpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
    <Set name="secureScheme">https</Set>
    <Set name="securePort">
        <Property name="jetty.secure.port" default="8443" />
    </Set>
    <Set name="outputBufferSize">32768</Set>
    <Set name="requestHeaderSize">8192</Set>
    <Set name="responseHeaderSize">8192</Set>
    <Set name="sendServerVersion">true</Set>
    <Set name="sendDateHeader">false</Set>
    <Set name="headerCacheSize">512</Set>
</New>

<New id="sslHttpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
    <Arg>
        <Ref refid="httpConfig" />
    </Arg>
    <Call name="addCustomizer">
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer" />
        </Arg>
    </Call>
</New>

<New id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
    <Set name="KeyStorePath">C:/keystore</Set>
    <Set name="KeyStorePassword">password</Set>
    <Set name="KeyManagerPassword">password</Set>
    <Set name="TrustStorePath">C:/keystore</Set>
    <Set name="TrustStorePassword">password</Set>
    <Set name="ExcludeCipherSuites">
        <Array type="String">
            <Item>SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</Item>
            <Item>SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</Item>
            <Item>SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</Item>
            <Item>SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5</Item>
            <Item>SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</Item>
            <Item>SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</Item>
            <Item>SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</Item>
        </Array>
    </Set>
</New>

<Call id="httpsConnector" name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
            <Arg name="server">
                <Ref refid="Server" />
            </Arg>
            <Arg name="factories">
                <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
                    <Item>
                        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory">
                            <Arg name="next">http/1.1</Arg>
                            <Arg name="sslContextFactory">
                                <Ref refid="sslContextFactory" />
                            </Arg>
                        </New>
                    </Item>
                    <Item>
                        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
                            <Arg name="config">
                                <Ref refid="sslHttpConfig" />
                            </Arg>
                        </New>
                    </Item>
                </Array>
            </Arg>
            <Set name="host">
                <Property name="jetty.host" />
            </Set>
            <Set name="port">
                <Property name="https.port" default="9443" />
            </Set>
            <Set name="idleTimeout">
                <Property name="https.timeout" default="30000" />
            </Set>
            <Set name="name">httpsConnector</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</Call>

<Call id="httpConnector" name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
            <Arg name="server">
                <Ref refid="Server" />
            </Arg>
            <Arg name="factories">
                <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
                    <Item>
                        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
                            <Arg name="config">
                                <Ref refid="httpConfig" />
                            </Arg>
                        </New>
                    </Item>
                </Array>
            </Arg>
            <Set name="host">
                <Property name="jetty.host" />
            </Set>
            <Set name="port">
                <Property name="jetty.port" default="8282" />
            </Set>
            <Set name="idleTimeout">
                <Property name="http.timeout" default="30000" />
            </Set>
            <Set name="name">httpConnector</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</Call>

<Get name="handler">
    <Call name="addHandler">
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler">
                <Set name="contextPath">/static-content</Set>
                <Set name="handler">
                    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler">
                        <Set name="resourceBase">target/logs</Set>
                        <Set name="directoriesListed">true</Set>
                    </New>
                </Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </Call>
</Get>
```

I didn't get any exceptions and the output contains the following lines:

```
17:19:02.401 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.e.j.u.component.ContainerLifeCycle - ServerConnector@31c30fbe{null}{0.0.0.0:0} added {org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerWrapper@5c079d6,UNMANAGED}
17:19:02.402 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.e.j.u.component.ContainerLifeCycle - ServerConnector@31c30fbe{null}{0.0.0.0:0} added {qtp1173186476{STOPPED,8<=0<=200,i=0,q=0},AUTO}
17:19:02.403 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.e.j.u.component.ContainerLifeCycle - ServerConnector@31c30fbe{null}{0.0.0.0:0} added {org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler@58716c6e,AUTO}
17:19:02.403 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.e.j.u.component.ContainerLifeCycle - ServerConnector@31c30fbe{null}{0.0.0.0:0} added {org.eclipse.jetty.io.ArrayByteBufferPool@296d1b9a,POJO}
17:19:02.404 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.e.j.u.component.ContainerLifeCycle - ServerConnector@31c30fbe{null}{0.0.0.0:0} added {SslConnectionFactory@1757e7bc{SSL-http/1.1},AUTO}
17:19:02.405 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.e.j.u.component.ContainerLifeCycle - ServerConnector@31c30fbe{SSL-http/1.1}{0.0.0.0:0} added {HttpConnectionFactory@2458f97{HTTP/1.1},AUTO}
17:19:02.407 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.e.j.u.component.ContainerLifeCycle - ServerConnector@31c30fbe{SSL-http/1.1}{0.0.0.0:0} added {org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector$ServerConnectorManager@5b9af7a6,MANAGED}
17:19:02.408 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration - XML ServerConnector@31c30fbe{SSL-http/1.1}{0.0.0.0:0}.setHost(null)
17:19:02.412 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration - XML ServerConnector@31c30fbe{SSL-http/1.1}{0.0.0.0:0}.setPort(9443)
17:19:02.413 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration - XML ServerConnector@31c30fbe{SSL-http/1.1}{0.0.0.0:9443}.setIdleTimeout(30000)
17:19:02.413 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration - XML ServerConnector@31c30fbe{SSL-http/1.1}{0.0.0.0:9443}.setName(httpsConnector)
17:19:02.414 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration - XML call addConnector
```

When I check the open ports via `netstat -an` the https port 9443 is not listed. What do I make wrong?

Comment: Why did you create a fragment bundle? What do you use to start the embedded jetty container? Do you use jetty-osgi-boot or you do it programmatically?

Comment: The log statements don't show the server and connectors being started.  Nothing listening until the connectors are started (via the server lifecycle start)

Comment: May I suggest to either peek at the way Pax Web solved it, or even use it instead? https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web